# Converting iff/ilbm image frames with no file extensions from old Amiga to MP4 video file. on PC

Tags: input

I'm using the following FFMPEG version.

> ffmpeg version N-89861-g78e884f3fb Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)

I have recovered some old animation frames from my old Amiga.
The frames are named like the following:

```
ANIM-000
ANIM-001
ANIM-002  
etc.
```

I have tried the following to encode to an mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i "ANIM-%03d" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I receive the following error:

> ANIM-%03d: No such file or directory

I have tried lots of different combinations of `ANIM-%03d*` and the like but have had no luck.

I assume FFMPEG will only work with files that have .extensions.

How to convert these files?

Answer (score 0):

According to the post
[ffmpeg .iff image sequence to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547774/ffmpeg-iff-image-sequence-to-video) :

> the problem was that ffmpeg does not support .iff format sequence, I tried with png and jpg it seems to work fine.

It seems then that you need to convert the IFF files to a modern image
format such as PNG or JPG.

My search has uncovered the following tools (which I never tested) :

- Website
  [Convert an image from IFF to the JPG format](https://tomseditor.com/convert/convert-image-from-IFF-to-JPG?l=en)
- [RECOIL](https://recoil.sourceforge.net/windows.html)
  adds an IFF plugin to several image editors as well as a standalone
  program
- Some image editors are said to be able to convert IFF :
  Ability Photopaint, Adobe Photoshop and XnConvert.

Comment: Thank you for your help, It must support iff / ilbm as if i use the following command it shows the correct format and resolution. ffmpeg -r 30 -i "ANIM-000" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 .    " Stream #0:0: Video: iff_ilbm (ILBM / 0x4D424C49), pal8, 320x200, SAR 10:11 DAR 16:11, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc" . From that I think the problem is the understanding of the input file name it could be Windows Dos that's letting it down.    PS I don't know if I should of replied via the comment button, but there didn't seem to be any other way.

Comment: Commenting is fine. The problem might be when producing the video.